# How to check whats the older timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm too noob when it comes to Dates. Anyone can help me in order to check which of two given unix timestamps represent an older date ? ie:

1379049923 (equivalent to - Fri, 13 Sep 2013 01:25:23)

1379049827 (equivalent to - Fri, 13 Sep 2013 01:23:47)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just see which number is smaller - 1379049827 is smaller than 1379049923, so the timestamp is earlier. The timestamp is *just* the number of seconds elapsed since the Unix epoch.

```
if ($first < $second)
    echo "first is earlier"
```

Comment: I understand, didn't know that is possible to compare them as integers lol. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just compare it as integers. Older date will be lower because timestamp is number of seconds from 01.01.1970